# Javascript to check if fields are entered for login

Tags: javascript, html, validation, authentication

I'm trying to create a login page.  I need to validate username and password but my js does not seem to work. I made it simpler now just for the sake to make it work. This is my html:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src = "js/checklogin.js"></script>
<h3>Already have an account?</h3>
            <span id = "feedback"></span>
            <form id = "login" action = "login.html"  method = "post">
                <label for = "name">User name:</label><br>
                <input type = "text" name = "username " id = "username"><br>
                <label for = "password">Password:</label><br>
                <input type = "password" name = "password" id = "password"><br> 

                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
```

And this is my js:

```
var elUsername = document.getElementById('username'); 
var elPassword = document.getElementById('password')
var elMsg = document.getElementById('feedback');      
function checkFilled(length) {                    
 if (length == "") {           
    elMsg.innerHTML = 'Please fill out this field';
 } else {                                            
  document.getElementById("login").submit();                        
}
}
elUsername.addEventListener('blur', checkFilled(elUsername.value),false);
elPassword.addEventListener('blur', checkFilled(elPassword.value),false);
```

I still cannot make it to work. Also, how can i make it to appear as a pop up right on the textbox? Something that looks like this:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oesjA.png)

Comment: How do you mean "does not seem to work"? Doesn't work how?

Comment: i don't get the message saying 'Please fill the field" and it goes on to redirect the page to login.html

Comment: When you click the Submit button?

Comment: i just added required to the html so that's done. Now i wanna make it so that it gives the message when i move focus from the text boxes.

Comment: Gimme a second, I've just about got a complete answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several issues with the code you had, so here's a complete example of the way I would do it (use the same HTML you already have). This works for me as tested in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmr4894b/2/) and below in the snippet.

```js
var elUsername = document.getElementById('username');
var elPassword = document.getElementById('password')
var elMsg = document.getElementById('feedback');
var elForm = document.getElementById('login');

function checkFilled() {
    if (elUsername.value == "" || elPassword.value == "") {
        elMsg.innerHTML = 'Please fill out this field';
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        elMsg.innerHTML = '';
    }
}

if (elForm.addEventListener) {
    elForm.addEventListener('submit', function() {
         checkFilled();
    }, false);
} else {
    elForm.attachEvent('onsubmit', function() {
         checkFilled();
    });
}

if (elUsername.addEventListener) {
    elUsername.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        checkFilled();
    }, false);
} else {
    elUsername.attachEvent('onblur', function() {
        checkFilled();
    });
}

if (elPassword.addEventListener) {
    elPassword.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        checkFilled();
    }, false);
} else {
    elPassword.attachEvent('onblur', function() {
        checkFilled();
    });
}
```

```html
<!--<script  type="text/javascript" src = "js/checklogin.js"></script>-->
<h3>Already have an account?</h3>
            <span id = "feedback"></span>
            <form id = "login" action = "login.html"  method = "post">
                <label for = "name">User name:</label><br>
                <input type = "text" name = "username " id = "username"><br>
                <label for = "password">Password:</label><br>
                <input type = "password" name = "password" id = "password"><br> 

                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
```

Comment: Thank you! this did it for me!